# Django, `KeyError <built-in function id>` in the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have created an app that give me the possibility to collect and store all daily income. In this case I have created the following model:

```
class Income(models.Model):
    income=models.DecimalField()
    date=models.DateField()
```

In my views I have created an algo that give me the possibility to collect all date monthly, like the following:

```
now=datetime.datetime.now()
now=now.year
income=dict()
for year, month, totals in(Income.objects.values_list( 'date__year', 'date__month').
            annotate(totals=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('income')),
            output_field=FloatField())).values_list('date__year', 'date__month', 'totals')):
            if id not in income.keys() and  year == now:
                income[id]=list(defaults)
            index=month-1
            income[id][index]=totals
```

All works perfectly. But now I want to give the possibility to be able to choose the year manage the `now` variable. So for this aim I have tried to create a new model, as the following:

```
class Timing(models.Model):
    TYPE=[
            ('2020','2020'),
            ('2021', '2021'),
    ]
    reference_year=models.CharField('Azienda/Privato', max_length=30, choices=TYPE, default="")
```

And in my views I have added the code:

```
now='2020'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TimingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            now = form.cleaned_data['reference_year']
```

But django give me the `KeyError <built-in function id>`. Where is the issue? I think that the problem is about the fact that now is not a datetime variable?

Comment: You did not pass a variable `id`, hence `id` is the builtin `id` function.

Comment: yes but if I use the first solution all works perfectly. Why when I add the forms all does not work?

Comment: because in the new context, there is no `id` variable...

Comment: How could solve it?

Comment: Could you give me an example solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in `if id not in income.keys() and  year == now:`
id - it's built-in function, you need use string 'id'.
also change this line `income[id]=list(defaults)`.